# Clojure: round bigInt in map

Tags: clojure

I need some help with maps. After I get data with `jdbc/query` from a database, the result looks like this:

```
({:product_id 1, :name product1, :rating 3.000M}
 {:product_id 2, :name product2, :rating 1.333M}
 {:product_id 3, :name product3}, :rating nil)
```

I want to display everything with Selmer, but I just want only 1 number after the comma. Something like this:

```
({:product_id 1, :name product1, :rating 3.0}
 {:product_id 2, :name product2, :rating 1.3}
 {:product_id 3, :name product3}, :rating nil)
```

I found out, how to iterate over a map, but i dont know how to change the specific value. The query data is saved in `data`

```
(doseq [keyval data]
  (doseq [keyval2 keyval]
    (doseq [keyval3 keyval2]
      (prn keyval3))))
```

Can you help me create a new `data` variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn round2
  "Round a double to the given precision (number of significant digits)"
  [precision d]
  (let [factor (Math/pow 10 precision)]
    (/ (Math/round (* d factor)) factor)))

(map #(assoc % :rating (when-some [r (:rating %)] (round2 1 r)))
    '({:product_id 1, :name 'product1, :rating 3.000M}
      {:product_id 2, :name 'product2, :rating 1.333M}
      {:product_id 3, :name 'product3, :rating nil}))
```

Comment: it would be more idiomatic to replace this part: `(if (nil? (:rating %)) nil (round2 1 (:rating %)))` with something like this: `(when-some [r (:rating %)] (round2 1 r))`

Comment: leetwinski, yes, you are right, I answered in hurry

Answer (score 2):

clojure data is immutable, so you can't update it in a common way. Rather you make the copy of your data adding the needed changes using clojure's data manipulation functions. Nice introduction can be found here: http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/

so what you do is something like this

```
user> (defn round-to [^Double num places] (when num (Math/round num)))
#'user/round-to ;; not-a-real-round-to (simplified for brevity)

user> (def data '({:product_id 1, :name product1, :rating 3.000M}
                  {:product_id 2, :name product2, :rating 1.333M}
                  {:product_id 3, :name product3, :rating nil}))
#'user/data

user> (map #(update % :rating round-to 2) data)
;;=> ({:product_id 1, :name product1, :rating 3} 
;;    {:product_id 2, :name product2, :rating 1} 
;;    {:product_id 3, :name product3, :rating nil})
```